# SWT Browser not setting http header properly - Accept-Language

Tags: java, swt

By the way sorry for my english.
Im trying to load in swt the contains of a http request to our report server. I did some research and finally have something like this.

```
final String[] header = new String[] {
                "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8",
                "Cache-Control: no-cache",
                "Accept: */*",
                "Referer: http://<my_own_server>/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fInformesLogistica%2fDistribucion%2fAETOrdenDevolucionReclamable",
                "Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch",
                "Accept-Language: es-ES,es;q=0.8",
                "Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3" };
String url = "http://axprerps/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fInformesLogistica%2fDistribucion%2fAETOrdenDevolucionReclamable&rc:Parameters=False";
String filters = "pCentroCompra=1&pCampana=16";
Browser myBrowser = new Browser(main, SWT.NONE);
myBrowser.setUrl(url, filters, header);
```

Its working pretty good but in some computers just fails because Locale.
If i put some kind of sniffer on my machine i can see which headers it sends:

```
Referer: http://axprerps/ReportServer/Pages/ReportViewer.aspx?%2fInformesLogistica%2fDistribucion%2fAETOrdenDevolucionReclamable\r\n
Accept-Language: es\r\n
User-Agent: Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 7.0; Windows NT 5.1; Trident/4.0; .NET CLR 1.1.4322; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.0.04506.30; .NET CLR 3.0.4506.2152; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; MS-RTC LM 8; .NET4.0C; InfoPath.2; .NET4.0E)\r\n
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8\r\n
Cache-Control: no-cache\r\n
Accept: */*\r\n
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate\r\n
Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3\r\n
Host: axprerps\r\n
Content-Length: 8047\r\n
Connection: Keep-Alive\r\n
```

My SO is windows XP SP3 but behavior is reproducible in Windows 2003 Server SP 2 also. I haven't tested it in any other SO.

So header for Accept-Language is just being ignored. Is this a normal behavior?

Cheers.